# How to detect straight lines on grayscale images？

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, straight-line-detection

I have some grayscale image，one of which is shown following：

[image: original]

This image is like a “disk” which contains a lot of noise in the non-black area. I want to detect the line in it. The line is easy to be seen by eyes but quite difficult to be seen by computer. I handed out this line for a better demonstration.

[image: show the line]

Now I've tried many methods，such as Hough Line transform, Radon transform and so on. However, it's hard to tell whether I used them in a wrong way or those methods do not apply to this task.

I am a beginner in image processing. Could anyone here provide some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is very hard because your line is noisy, so it's not really a line. Maybe you can preprocess the image and then apply hough to it. Try some binarization and some dilation and erosion. Not sure it will work

Comment: I would like to iterate over radius and angle and to find it manually by a simple peak detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Gabor filters. Here is a start:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHA7w.png');
% gray out empty spaces
img(img == 0) = 123;
% create gabor filter bank
wavelength = 6;
orientation = 5:5:180;
g = gabor(wavelength,orientation);
outMag = imgaborfilt(img,g);
% plot the magnitude at peak orientation
ii = 23;
figure
imagesc(outMag(:,:,ii))
title(['Magnitude at ',num2str(orientation(ii)),'deg'])
% create a mask
mask = outMag(:,:,ii) > 250;
figure;
imshow(mask)
```

You still have to detect in which layer you got high magnitude, and filter the mask to hide the edges and small patches.